# Image file not fully copied

Tags: java

I am using following program to get file from server:

```
 public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 12345);
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024];
        InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("E://cy.jpg");
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        int bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        bos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);

        bos.close();
        sock.close();
  }
```

This is creating the file but only a few contents of the image are being copied.
Can someone please explain what is wrong with this code and how to fix it?

Comment: Looks like your are only reading the first 1024 byte. A loop should help.

Comment: are you sure you are using the same buffer size for receiving as the socket uses for sending? and maybe loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading only 1024 bytes from `InputStream`. You need wrap reading by `while` loop:

```
int bytesRead ;
while ((bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray)) != -1) {
      bos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Comment: your code can throw IndexOutOfBoundsException. Might have to do b.length - off.length - offset

Comment: @Ata I don't see case when it can throw IndexOutOfBoundException. Could you provide the case?

Comment: I suppose when you have already read some bytes and you try to read the original length again. Not sure if that's applicable for sockets

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

    public class Test
    {
        public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
            Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 12345);
            InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("E://cy.jpg");
            IOUtils.copy(is, fos);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(fos);
            sock.close();

        }
    }
```

This code uses [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/package-summary.html) from [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)